# What is the better way to make gallery image in website?

Tags: jquery, image

i want to make some web which is consist of image. This web is for visual information for our product, so if someone comes and want to see what kind of our product. They can find out by themselves all part of our product.

could you give me some advice which program of jquery that I can use for make it?
any tutorials would be appreciate..

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want your products to be shown.
e.g.

Product with thumbnail, image and description:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-rotator/

You can even use this for individual product gallery for multiple images.

I prefer coding my own custom gallery to suite my needs, but sometimes time is an issue.

Comment: lets say i want to group image by camera. then I want to show various of brand like image of sony camera, canon,etc.then the 2nd group is handphone, then show: samsung, nokia, etc. which the suited way for this program?

Comment: I tried finding a plugin to match your requirements, but was unsuccessful. It would be best if group your products and sub-categories on a main page[html], that clicks through to your gallery, passing through values to controls which images will be shown.